# npm cron v1.4.0 not workin

Tags: node.js, npm, cron

```
const 
    CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

(async function() {

    // Defining the cron
    const job = new CronJob({
        cronTime: '* * * * * *',
        onTick: () => {console.log("ok")},
        timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
        start: true
    });

})();
```

cron version 1.4.0

This doesn't print ok every second on v1.4.0
whereas v1.3.0 prints ok every second

So is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the API has changed on this package...

This is an example from the latest documentation on github https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#readme

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

I would give it a try like that

Comment: not working now, bcoz, can't stop from inside another function

Answer (score 0):

I think Some bugs found

```
const { log } = require('console');
const cron = require('node-cron');
let i = 0;

console.log("Hello World");
const task = cron.schedule('* * * * * *', () => {
  _find();
  task.stop();
  console.log('running a task every 1 second');
},{
  scheduled: false
});;

function _find() {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  _checking(i);
}

function _checking(i) {
  if(i===0){
    console.log('started')
  task.start();
  }
  else if (i > 3) {
    console.log('yes');
    task.stop();
    console.log('stopped');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
_checking(i);
```